# Cursor Appears after content attribute of CSS in Internet explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

Please check the below jsfiddle example

http://jsfiddle.net/KX6BY/1/

```
<div contenteditable="true" id="sud"></div>
#sud
{
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
top: 50px;
left: 50px;
border: 1px solid black;
}

#sud:empty:before
{
content:"hello"
}
```

In all major browsers like Chrome, Firefox, Safari on focus of the input field cursor appears at the beginning(on top of content) But in Internet explorer, The cursor appears after content. Is there any workaround for this??

Answer (score 0):

Working solution: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/avi_sagi/KX6BY/5/)

By specifying `position:absolute` to the `:before` psuedoclass and giving `top:` value equal to line-height computed to the text u can have uniform functionality in all browsers.

```
#sud:empty:before
{
content:"hello";
position:absolute;
top:8px;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I am facing issues with IE10 with the above changes.. Cursor does not appears properly at the beginning. It appears above the focussed element. Do you have any idea about this???